# Getting error while using sftp (get: Invalid Flag -r)

Tags: rhel, remote, file-copy, sftp

I want to copy a few folders from Server A (/aaa/bbb/ccc/) to Server B (/xxx/yyy/zzz/), considering Server A is source and Server B is destination.

There are multiple folders in ccc/ which need to be copied inside zzz/.

I tried using sftp which is only available option for me and should be executed from destination not from source and tried to connect source

```
In Console (SERVER B) :

 [user zzz]$ sftp hostname.domain.com

 ------ Connected -------

 sftp> get -r /aaa/bbb/ccc/
```

It returns:

> get : Invalid flag -r

Server we are using is RedHat Enterprise, Need to copy the folders.

**EDIT 1.**

```
sftp> get -r / aaa / bbb / ccc /
get: Invalid flag -r
sftp> Write failed: Broken pipe

sftp> version
SFTP protocol version 3
```

Comment: Does your man page for `sftp` suggest that '-r' is a valid option ?  `man sftp | grep "get "`

Comment: You say, “There are multiple folders in ccc/ which need to be copied inside ddd/.” Do you mean, “There are multiple folders in ccc/ which need to be copied into ***zzz/***.”?

Comment: What is your version of `sftp`? It may be that only the `-P` flag is implemented for the `get` command in the version you're using. Check your manual.

Comment: @Scott Yes My Mistake, it should be copied into zzz/

Comment: @steve It returned nothing when I ran 
man sftp | grep "get "

Comment: @user308967 so that suggests your `sftp` simply doesn't support '-r' option.  Worth looking into using `rsync`, see `man rsync`.

Comment: okay, Thanks, @steve. Btw I tried to copy all contents without < -r > and it worked for me. Command [ sftp ] >>> get /aaa/bbb/ccc/* /xxx/yyy/zzz/

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
sftp -r server@address
sftp> get /dir/to/path/files/
```

You could also try wildcards to get this to work as well.

```
sftp> get /dir/to/path/files/*
sftp> get /dir/to/path/files/*. *  #minus the space after the period.
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting Jeff, how did you do that?